# python read file output from certain string value

Tags: python, io, operating-system, readfile

I want to read the text file from the part where it prints Network Cards and continue from there, but i dont have a clue how to do this.

```
import os


def main():
    print "This is a file handling system"
    fileHandler()

def fileHandler():
    os.system('systeminfo>file.txt')
    foo = open('file.txt', 'r+')
    readFile = foo.read()
    x = readFile.startswith('Network Card')
    print x
    foo.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to save the subprocess output to a file first. You could redirect its stdout to a pipe:

```
from subprocess import check_output

after_network_card = check_output("systeminfo").partition("Network Card")[2]
```

`after_network_card` contains output from `systeminfo` that comes after the first "Network Card"`.

If you have access to the output as a file object then to get the part starting with the line with `"Network Card"`:

```
from itertools import dropwhile

with open('file.txt') as file:
    lines = dropwhile(lambda line: "Network Card" not in line, file)
```

You could also use explicit `for`-loop:

```
for line in file:
    if "Network Card" in line:
       break
# use `file` here
```

A file is an iterator over lines in Python.

Comment: Using subprocess would be better, but i don't really understand how i should print out only the wanted information.

`ps = subprocess.Popen(['systeminfo'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()

print ps`

this gives me the output for the command systeminfo on Windows OS.
But i don't want the extra information like hotfixes.

Comment: `after_network_card` variable above contains the info you wanted

Comment: `ps = subprocess.Popen(['systeminfo'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
    after_network_card = ps.check_output('systeminfo').partition("Netword Card(s) ")[2]
    print after_network_card`

Like this ?

Comment: just copy-paste the first code example from my answer

Comment: Great, thank you !
How do i control it where to stop the information printing?

Comment: `after_network_card` is a string. It has many methods that you could use. You could also apply a regex to it. Or write a parser specific for your case to extract the info. In other words, *"stop the information printing"* solution is specific in each case

Comment: How am i supposed to use regex for finding the wanted information.

`for line in after_network_card:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if re.search('Network:', line):
            print line
        else:
            print "nothing"
            exit(0)`

Comment: Try `for character in "abc": print character` in Python console, to understand that iterating over a string yield characters, not lines. It is not clear what information you are trying to extract. [ask new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), be specific, include input and the expected output, show your current attempts to get this output, provide larger context to see what is your final goal