# Python: Systeminfo prints only network card

Tags: python, regex, subprocess

Hi so am trying to print information with `systeminfo` (Windows OS command) using subprocess.
I have managed to find the wanted string with `re.search()`, but it only gives me the result code. 
Anyways what i want to do is start printing from Network card(s) and print until all information is provided for that particular part and leave the rest unused.

```
import subprocess
import re
def main():
    print "This is a system info handling program"
    infoHandler()

def infoHandler():
    after_network_card = subprocess.check_output('systeminfo')
    searchLine = re.search("Network", after_network_card)

    print searchLine

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: How *"that particular part"* is delimited from the rest of the output? How do you find where it ends? Please, provide example input and the expected output as [I've asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22529862/python-read-file-output-from-certain-string-value#comment34289065_22529935)

Comment: can you specify which OS?  What is the expected output?

Comment: unrelated: do not name it `after_network_card` if you've omitted [`.partition("Network Card")` part from my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22529935/4279)

Comment: I want only to print the network card information until the end of ip-address of the network card.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Network Cards(s)` resides at the end of your info, then you can use this regex with `findall()`.

```
searchLine = re.findall("Network Card\S*:([\s\S]*:[a-f0-9]{4}:[a-f0-9]{4})", after_network_card)
print searchLine[0]
```

Comment: How do i prevent it from printing after the MAC-address is printed?

Comment: @user3441458 probaby replacing with `"Network Card\S*:([\s\S]*:[a-f0-9]{4}:[a-f0-9]{4})"` inside the regex in `findall`. I have added `:[a-f0-9]{4}:[a-f0-9]{4}` at the regex so that it match something like `:dc77:33f6`